# My vba code isnt looping until my desired number. but if i put it in excel and use solver it works

Tags: excel, vba, loops

For VBA i have some code written just to see what the exact problem is just for this code. I was wondering if anybody could go through it and check it out for me. Its not much at all. I just need E1act and E2act to not be negative and converge to a reasonable number.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Tf = 1023.15
Po = 11.8431
N1 = 1600
R = 1
Kp1 = 10 ^ (-(11769 / Tf) + 13.1927)

Kp2 = 10 ^ (-(1197.8 / Tf) - 1.6485)

E1act = 1

E2act = 0.1

Z=1

Do

E1ini = E1act

E2ini = E2act

E1act = (((((N1 * (1 + R) + 2 * E1ini) ^ 2) * (N1 - E1ini) * ((N1 * R) - E1ini - E2ini) * Kp1) / (((3 * E1ini + E2ini) ^ 3) * Po ^ 2)) + E2ini)

E2act = (Kp2 * (E1ini - E2ini) * ((N1 * R) - E1ini - E2ini)) / ((3 * E1ini) - E2ini)
Sheet1.Range("A" & Z) = E1act
Sheet1.Range("B" & Z) = E2act
Loop Until Abs(E1ini - E1act) <= 0.1 And Abs(E2ini - E2act) <= 0.1
Z=Z+1
End Sub
```

Comment: `converge to a reasonable number` what's reasonable? Edit: what is `Tf`?

Comment: Sheet1.range is just there so i can view the numbers calculated

Comment: That doesn't answer my question or I don't understand. What is `z` doing??

Comment: sorry i just edited it, forgot to add my statements

Comment: Sigh. So many questions but there's nothing incrementing within the loop?

Comment: I ran those E1act and E2act formulas in to a cell in excel and ran solver for changing e1ini and e2ini and after 5 solvers it comes out with around a 1200 value for e1act but in vba it says overflow

Comment: Add "Option Explicit" as the first line in the class/module/etc file, and declare variables before you use them (with Dim). Also before the 'Loop Until...' add Debug.Print(CStr(E1ini) + "; " + CStr(E1act")) and check return values in immediate window

Comment: The solver is doing lots of stuff behind the scenes. If you want to imitate it, you need to do all of that yourself. Your loop is useless if it doesn't increment.

Comment: ah, solver. didn't see that. do what @findwindow says then :)

Comment: Z is moving the output number down for every loop

Comment: increment meaning?

Comment: @elDirtyDuderino Z=Z+1 you mean? That's outside the loop

Comment: I don't think you're ready to imitate the solver. (I am not ready myself) Why can't you just use solver?

Comment: The teacher wants this all done in VBA

Comment: But never taught us any where close as what is needed for this project and tells me to google things if i have questions

Comment: yeah the Z=Z+1 should be referring to the placement in my excel sheet for outputs

Comment: Good teacher. You should google things and try to figure it out on your own. I would google how `loop` operate. OR ask your teacher.

Comment: I have many of times googled tons of examples and try everything that is on there but cant seem to still get it to work. this is actually just 1 very small part of the project and still have alot more to work on after words but my numbers wont work until this works, so my graphs popping up are useless

Comment: I can see you put it effort. I am asking you to research `loop` specifically. Your understanding of it is incomplete.

Comment: Do the Debug.Print I wrote above for a better understand what actually is going on :)

Comment: I have over 10 webpages open to loop statements and for loops because ill end up needing to do a nested loop. but no website i have found or videos on youtube have helped me much and im not sure why. we werent even given a text book to look over

Comment: That sucks :/ Seems like you need a break ^_^; Take one and come back.

Comment: Debug.Print("CStr(E1ini) + "; " + CStr(E1act))

Comment: added that and it says the ; is wrong and yes i added the option explicit

Comment: never mind deleted the " and it takes it

Comment: it doesnt run with option explicit and the debug code......it says define variable and highlights Tf

Comment: variable not defined i mean

Comment: I am going home so you're on your own. Remove the `option explicit`. That's not important right now. Do the `debug.print` as @Mark said. That should help you to understand `loop`.

Comment: I would also stick with option explicit to avoid vb-magic :) But it's your call of course ;)

Comment: The problem is in the math - the series just never converge.

Comment: I see that in the numbers....it gets close between it being looped 7 to 8 times but how might i get the correct answer using loop statements for that

Comment: @Comintern if you have any help with it converging to a actual number i would surely appreciate it.....then i can move onto making graphs and charts from this data

Comment: The math's a bit over my head, I'm afraid. You might want to edit your question to include the equation you're trying to use though. Maybe update the title to indicate that it's a problem with an algorithm and not a loop.  That may attract better answers.

Comment: I cannot make it converge in solver, or manually. I think there's a problem in your equations and/or bracket locations.